# SPARQL - File with more than 56000 triples - how to check conditions in one time

Tags: sparql, rdf

I am new at SPARQL. I have a (for me) huge RDF/XML file from Project Gutenberg and I'm trying to have a list of books having some specific qualities. The book should be from "fictional" genre and be written in English.

I would like to use SPARQL to create this filter. I know for example how to do simple queries (retrieve for example the title of the book) but when I have to create complex queries I get lost.

Once my query is ended and once I know that it is a fictional book, I would like to retrieve information such as: author, language, title and ID.

This is an extract from the RDF/XML file.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rdf:RDF xml:base="http://www.gutenberg.org/"
  xmlns:cc="http://web.resource.org/cc/"
  xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
  xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/"
  xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
  xmlns:dcam="http://purl.org/dc/dcam/"
  xmlns:pgterms="http://www.gutenberg.org/2009/pgterms/"
>
  <cc:Work rdf:about="">
    <rdfs:comment>Archives containing the RDF files for *all* our books can be downloaded at
            http://www.gutenberg.org/wiki/Gutenberg:Feeds#The_Complete_Project_Gutenberg_Catalog</rdfs:comment>
    <cc:license rdf:resource="https://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/"/>
  </cc:Work>

  <pgterms:ebook rdf:about="ebooks/123">
    <dcterms:hasFormat>
      <pgterms:file rdf:about="http://www.gutenberg.org/files/123/123-h/123-h.htm">
        <dcterms:format>
          <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="N2c0860e4a086416ca54377ad8d2feb3a">
            <dcam:memberOf rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/terms/IMT"/>
            <rdf:value rdf:datatype="http://purl.org/dc/terms/IMT">text/html; charset=iso-8859-1</rdf:value>
          </rdf:Description>
        </dcterms:format>
        <dcterms:extent rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">309310</dcterms:extent>
        <dcterms:modified rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime">2012-07-19T10:37:04</dcterms:modified>
        <dcterms:isFormatOf rdf:resource="ebooks/123"/>
      </pgterms:file>
    </dcterms:hasFormat>

    <dcterms:subject>
      <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="Na447b67898ca445eb5df7fe22decdcc8">
        <dcam:memberOf rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/terms/LCSH"/>
        <rdf:value>Science fiction</rdf:value>
      </rdf:Description>
    </dcterms:subject>
    <dcterms:type>
      <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="Nc3bf0165309d49cc9ff92b4f34bf3d0b">
        <rdf:value>Text</rdf:value>
        <dcam:memberOf rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/terms/DCMIType"/>
      </rdf:Description>
    </dcterms:type>
    <dcterms:hasFormat>
      <pgterms:file rdf:about="http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/123.txt.utf-8">
        <dcterms:isFormatOf rdf:resource="ebooks/123"/>
        <dcterms:modified rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime">2017-10-01T01:21:10.697628</dcterms:modified>
        <dcterms:extent rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">294801</dcterms:extent>
        <dcterms:format>
          <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="N69057b2da52d4b848e6b7ab307920347">
            <rdf:value rdf:datatype="http://purl.org/dc/terms/IMT">text/plain</rdf:value>
            <dcam:memberOf rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/terms/IMT"/>
          </rdf:Description>
        </dcterms:format>
      </pgterms:file>
    </dcterms:hasFormat>
    <dcterms:language>
      <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="N3e77dee5bbbb413089732da352a8a605">
        <rdf:value rdf:datatype="http://purl.org/dc/terms/RFC4646">en</rdf:value>
      </rdf:Description>
    </dcterms:language>
    <dcterms:rights>Public domain in the USA.</dcterms:rights>
    <dcterms:title>At the Earth's Core</dcterms:title>
    <dcterms:description>Pellucidar</dcterms:description>
    <dcterms:subject>
      <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="N0748f419c34e4f75abdf52404dcbd879">
        <rdf:value>Adventure stories</rdf:value>
        <dcam:memberOf rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/terms/LCSH"/>
      </rdf:Description>
    </dcterms:subject>
    <dcterms:issued rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date">1994-04-01</dcterms:issued>
    <dcterms:hasFormat>
      <pgterms:file rdf:about="http://www.gutenberg.org/files/123/123.txt">
        <dcterms:isFormatOf rdf:resource="ebooks/123"/>
        <dcterms:extent rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">294829</dcterms:extent>
        <dcterms:modified rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime">2012-07-19T10:36:58</dcterms:modified>
        <dcterms:format>
          <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="Ndcd1e1ce476947bc8c2144c400182de4">
            <dcam:memberOf rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/terms/IMT"/>
            <rdf:value rdf:datatype="http://purl.org/dc/terms/IMT">text/plain; charset=us-ascii</rdf:value>
          </rdf:Description>
        </dcterms:format>
      </pgterms:file>
    </dcterms:hasFormat>
    <dcterms:subject>
      <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="N880067e98e604133b01bd7b752a86b07">
        <rdf:value>Earth (Planet) -- Core -- Fiction</rdf:value>
        <dcam:memberOf rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/terms/LCSH"/>
      </rdf:Description>
    </dcterms:subject>
    <dcterms:hasFormat>
      <pgterms:file rdf:about="http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/123.epub.noimages">
        <dcterms:extent rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">120042</dcterms:extent>
        <dcterms:format>
          <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="N3eba62c48ab24374b1e3acc96aae9db3">
            <dcam:memberOf rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/terms/IMT"/>
            <rdf:value rdf:datatype="http://purl.org/dc/terms/IMT">application/epub+zip</rdf:value>
          </rdf:Description>
        </dcterms:format>
        <dcterms:modified rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime">2017-10-01T01:21:11.287607</dcterms:modified>
        <dcterms:isFormatOf rdf:resource="ebooks/123"/>
      </pgterms:file>
    </dcterms:hasFormat>
    <dcterms:hasFormat>
      <pgterms:file rdf:about="http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/123.kindle.images">
        <dcterms:modified rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime">2017-10-01T01:21:12.665594</dcterms:modified>
        <dcterms:isFormatOf rdf:resource="ebooks/123"/>
        <dcterms:format>
          <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="N32c49cff0f9947b697e4690f5e80fb45">
            <dcam:memberOf rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/terms/IMT"/>
            <rdf:value rdf:datatype="http://purl.org/dc/terms/IMT">application/x-mobipocket-ebook</rdf:value>
          </rdf:Description>
        </dcterms:format>
        <dcterms:extent rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">501780</dcterms:extent>
      </pgterms:file>
    </dcterms:hasFormat>
    <dcterms:creator>
      <pgterms:agent rdf:about="2009/agents/48">
        <pgterms:name>Burroughs, Edgar Rice</pgterms:name>
        <pgterms:deathdate rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">1950</pgterms:deathdate>
        <pgterms:webpage rdf:resource="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edgar_Rice_Burroughs"/>
        <pgterms:birthdate rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">1875</pgterms:birthdate>
      </pgterms:agent>
    </dcterms:creator>
    <dcterms:publisher>Project Gutenberg</dcterms:publisher>
    <dcterms:license rdf:resource="license"/>
    <dcterms:hasFormat>
      <pgterms:file rdf:about="http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/123.rdf">
        <dcterms:format>
          <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="Nc0303d16343845c698d57f6fff44420f">
            <dcam:memberOf rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/terms/IMT"/>
            <rdf:value rdf:datatype="http://purl.org/dc/terms/IMT">application/rdf+xml</rdf:value>
          </rdf:Description>
        </dcterms:format>
        <dcterms:modified rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime">2018-05-17T05:00:17.585186</dcterms:modified>
        <dcterms:isFormatOf rdf:resource="ebooks/123"/>
        <dcterms:extent rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">12268</dcterms:extent>
      </pgterms:file>
    </dcterms:hasFormat>
    <dcterms:subject>
      <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="N483a91a4b85a4618be4ea92726b976a0">
        <dcam:memberOf rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/terms/LCC"/>
        <rdf:value>PS</rdf:value>
      </rdf:Description>
    </dcterms:subject>
    <dcterms:hasFormat>
      <pgterms:file rdf:about="http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/123.epub.images">
        <dcterms:format>
          <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="N11355a7445a8454d8fb33ecbd752949d">
            <dcam:memberOf rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/terms/IMT"/>
            <rdf:value rdf:datatype="http://purl.org/dc/terms/IMT">application/epub+zip</rdf:value>
          </rdf:Description>
        </dcterms:format>
        <dcterms:extent rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">120040</dcterms:extent>
        <dcterms:isFormatOf rdf:resource="ebooks/123"/>
        <dcterms:modified rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime">2017-10-01T01:21:11.093621</dcterms:modified>
      </pgterms:file>
    </dcterms:hasFormat>
    <dcterms:subject>
      <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="N6bf1581faa564781b44875beb4afd885">
        <rdf:value>Fantasy fiction</rdf:value>
        <dcam:memberOf rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/terms/LCSH"/>
      </rdf:Description>
    </dcterms:subject>
    <dcterms:hasFormat>
      <pgterms:file rdf:about="http://www.gutenberg.org/files/123/123.zip">
        <dcterms:format>
          <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="N9dc3758187eb4063bcb6b728000aa222">
            <rdf:value rdf:datatype="http://purl.org/dc/terms/IMT">application/zip</rdf:value>
            <dcam:memberOf rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/terms/IMT"/>
          </rdf:Description>
        </dcterms:format>
        <dcterms:isFormatOf rdf:resource="ebooks/123"/>
        <dcterms:format>
          <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="N43cf23a45ac1484a88bcad1e6af81564">
            <dcam:memberOf rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/terms/IMT"/>
            <rdf:value rdf:datatype="http://purl.org/dc/terms/IMT">text/plain; charset=us-ascii</rdf:value>
          </rdf:Description>
        </dcterms:format>
        <dcterms:modified rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime">2012-07-19T10:37:28</dcterms:modified>
        <dcterms:extent rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">112146</dcterms:extent>
      </pgterms:file>
    </dcterms:hasFormat>
    <dcterms:hasFormat>
      <pgterms:file rdf:about="http://www.gutenberg.org/files/123/123-h.zip">
        <dcterms:extent rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">114129</dcterms:extent>
        <dcterms:modified rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime">2012-07-19T10:37:28</dcterms:modified>
        <dcterms:format>
          <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="Nbe9881c4945a49eca8219a3cecdc70bd">
            <rdf:value rdf:datatype="http://purl.org/dc/terms/IMT">application/zip</rdf:value>
            <dcam:memberOf rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/terms/IMT"/>
          </rdf:Description>
        </dcterms:format>
        <dcterms:isFormatOf rdf:resource="ebooks/123"/>
        <dcterms:format>
          <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="Nc92f3d9ab6164c7eb7f56fa64a78d2ef">
            <rdf:value rdf:datatype="http://purl.org/dc/terms/IMT">text/html; charset=iso-8859-1</rdf:value>
            <dcam:memberOf rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/terms/IMT"/>
          </rdf:Description>
        </dcterms:format>
      </pgterms:file>
    </dcterms:hasFormat>
    <dcterms:hasFormat>
      <pgterms:file rdf:about="http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/123.kindle.noimages">
        <dcterms:modified rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime">2017-10-01T01:21:14.044548</dcterms:modified>
        <dcterms:isFormatOf rdf:resource="ebooks/123"/>
        <dcterms:extent rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">501774</dcterms:extent>
        <dcterms:format>
          <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="N0878de4bb93e4612b7088ba1d16d9509">
            <dcam:memberOf rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/terms/IMT"/>
            <rdf:value rdf:datatype="http://purl.org/dc/terms/IMT">application/x-mobipocket-ebook</rdf:value>
          </rdf:Description>
        </dcterms:format>
      </pgterms:file>
    </dcterms:hasFormat>
    <pgterms:bookshelf>
      <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="N1ba815d6c47845bf8e6e3b96920d40dc">
        <rdf:value>Science Fiction</rdf:value>
        <dcam:memberOf rdf:resource="2009/pgterms/Bookshelf"/>
      </rdf:Description>
    </pgterms:bookshelf>
    <pgterms:downloads rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">178</pgterms:downloads>
  </pgterms:ebook>


  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edgar_Rice_Burroughs">
    <dcterms:description>Wikipedia</dcterms:description>
  </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Comment: I understand that what people call "huge" is subjective, but I would consider 56,000 triples a small-to-medium size RDF graph. A few million triples is big, a few billion is huge, IMHO.

Comment: @AntoineZimmermann for me it's "huge" because it's the first time that I have this kind of file. I always worked on examples. Anyway, do you have any hint for my problem?

Comment: I would like to help you but I have to parse your RDF/XML extract, which is *huge*! ... just kidding, nevermind :) How to you decide that a book is functional? Is it sufficient that the word "fiction" appears in the `rdf:value` property of the `dcterms:subject`? BTW, it seems that your RDF graph is using `rdf:value` as if it was `rdfs:label`.

Comment: @AntoineZimmermann yes I would like to retrieve all the books with the word "fiction" in that property. In addition to this the book should be written in English. I am working with Fuseki-Jena and my goal, but I don't know if it is possible, is to have several columns with these pieces of info: author, title, language, book_id, html_link, genre.

Comment: for the future, plase look at your data as N-Triples, not RDF/XML - nobody wants to read RDF/XML, it's made for machines. and also, please post only RDF/XML here. your project isn'T big, conversion tools like rapper, riot, rdf4j, etc. exist

Comment: @AKSW wait, so nobody wants to read RDF but I should post only RDF here? Anyway this doesn't answer to my question.

Comment: When did I say this? RDF is a data model, RDF/XML, Turtle, N-Triples, etc. are serialization formats. Obviously, RDF/XML is very verbose or not? Obviously, N-Triples more naturally reflects triple syntax or not? Given just subject, predicate and object for each statement is at least for me easier to read and understand. Moreover, SPARQL is made of triple patterns as it's "core unit", basically the same as triples with the variables. Now tell me, what is more natural when creating a query, looking at N-Triples and maybe just replace an object by a variable, or look at XML? Just my two cents...

Comment: And of course this doesn't answer it, it was already given below. Was just a hint how it's easier to create SPARQL queries. But I don't care.

Comment: @AKSW thanks for your hint! Anyway I think that it is subjective. I work very often with XML and for this reason RDF-XML it's easy for me to read. Moreover it is the original file, I didn't create it and I am not sure to know how to translate it to another serialization format. That's because I am just new to this field - reason why I also ask question on the subject. Considered all this, it was easier for me to post directly the question using what I have that I am sure it's OK 100%.

Comment: "please post only RDF/XML here" was an error.  "please post only Turtle or N-Triples here" is what @AKSW meant.

Comment: RDF/XML is excessively verbose, and is hard for most people to parse quickly. N-Triples and Turtle are significantly more succinct, and typically much easier for people to parse quickly, which is key when helping people on sites like SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all books with the word 'fiction' in the `dcterms:subject` label, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?book
WHERE { 
  ?book dcterms:subject [ rdf:value ?g ] .
  FILTER(REGEX(STR(?g), "fiction", "i")) 
}
```

This query grabs all resources that have a `dcterms:subject` value that in turn has a `rdf:value` property with a value `?g`. The `FILTER` condition then checks that that value `?g` contains the word 'fiction'.

To grab additional properties of the books returned, simply expand on the query. For example to get back the book title as well, you'd do something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?book ?title
WHERE { 
  ?book dcterms:title ?title;
        dcterms:subject [ rdf:value ?g ] .
  FILTER(REGEX(STR(?g), "fiction", "i")) 
}
```

Hopefully this gets you started, with the help of a SPARQL tutorial and some elbow grease you should be able to expand upon this.

Comment: Can I insert in the same query also properties that are different from dcterms? Is there a tutorial for dummies to learn queries? I searched a lot for it but I have just found or too simple or too complicated tutorials

Comment: You can, yes. As for tutorials or books: "Learning SPARQL" by Bob duCharme is excellent. Not free, but worth it. See www.learningsparql.com